# Write one generic kernel and map it to different ISAs

Tags: c++, code-generation, template-meta-programming, generic-programming

UPDATE II: I wrote two examples to illustrate the ideas proposed in the accepted answer and comments. The first one `math_cmp.cc` performs explicit typed operations.

```
// math_cmp.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;

    float res = (a + b) * (a - b);

    cout << res << endl;

    __m128 a_vec, b_vec, res_vec;
    a_vec = _mm_set1_ps(a);
    b_vec = _mm_set1_ps(b);
    res_vec = _mm_mul_ps(_mm_add_ps(a_vec, b_vec),
            _mm_sub_ps(a_vec, b_vec));

    float *res_ptr;
    res_ptr = (float *) &res_vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    cout << "RES[" << i << "]: " << res_ptr[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The second file `math_traits.cc` performs the **template + traits**. The assembly generated when compiled with `-O3` is almost identical to that of `math_cmp.cc`.

```
// math_traits.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class MathOps
{
};

template <typename T>
T kernel (T a, T b)
{
    T res = MathOps<T>::mul(MathOps<T>::add(a, b), MathOps<T>::sub(a, b));

    return res;
}

template <>
class MathOps <float>
{
public:
    static float add (float a, float b)
    {
    return a + b;
    }

    static float sub (float a, float b)
    {
    return a - b;
    }

    static float mul (float a, float b)
    {
    return a * b;
    }
};

template <>
class MathOps <__m128>
{
public:
    static __m128 add (__m128 a, __m128 b)
    {
    return a + b;
    }

    static __m128 sub (__m128 a, __m128 b)
    {
    return a - b;
    }

    static __m128 mul (__m128 a, __m128 b)
    {
    return a * b;
    }
};

int main ()
{
    float a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << kernel<float>(a, b) << endl;

    __m128 a_vec, b_vec, res_vec;
    a_vec = _mm_set1_ps(a);
    b_vec = _mm_set1_ps(b);
    res_vec = kernel<__m128>(a_vec, b_vec);

    float *res_ptr;
    res_ptr = (float *) &res_vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    cout << "RES[" << i << "]: " << res_ptr[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

UPDATE I: I guess the question can be summarized as: **"Is there a modern C++ approach that is equivalent to *polymorphic* function-like macros?"**

---

I wonder if it is possible to program in C++ to write one kernel with the abstract operations, and automatically produce ISA-specific codes. For example, a generic kernel can be:

```
RET_TYPE kernel(IN_TYPE a, IN_TYPE b)
{
    RET_TYPE res = ADD(a, b);
    return res;
}
```

And the kernel can be transformed into *both* a scalar version:

```
float kernel(float a, float b)
{
    float res = a + b;
    return res;
}
```

and a vectorized version:

```
__m128 kernel(__m128 a, __m128 b)
{
    __m128 res = _mm_add_ps(a, b);
    return res;
}
```

In reality, the generic kernels would be much more complex. The genericity in the types can be handled by template parameters. But the genericity of the instructions got me stuck.

Usually, this kind of problem is addressed via *Code Generation*, where you write the program in some *Intermediate Representation (IR)* and then translate the IR expression into various target language.

However, I have to do it within *pure and modern* C++, meaning no C macros. I wonder if it's achievable by cleverly exploiting **Generic Programming**, **Template Metaprogramming** or **OOP**. Please help if you have some pointers!

Comment: Have you investigated existing libraries for template-based parallel programming in C++? Your last paragraph makes it seem as though this is a homework assignment, however.

Comment: @JAB I would assume the question is beyond the usual scope of any C++ homework assignment. But I could be wrong. The constraint in the last paragraph is due to the existing project design.

Comment: @JAB. Added the examples to illustrate the idea. Let me know if it makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it's achievable with templates and type traits:

```
template <typename T>
T kernel(T a, T b)
{
     return MathTraits<T>::add (a, b);
}
template <typename T>
class MathTraits 
{
}
// specialization for float
template <>
class MathTraits <float>
{
     float add(float a, float b)
     {
          return a+b;
     }
}
// specialization of MathTraits for __m128 etc.
```

However, this approach may fail when you may want to treat the same type differently in different situations. But that's general limit of overloading...

With the example given it's actually possible to directly specialize the function but the way described is more common as it's more clear and reusable.

Comment: Thank you @Zbynek Vyskovsky - kvr000. This looks like it might work. But I guess the performance would deteriorate due to the use of the wrapper class `MathTraits` and the function call overhead. I could force inlining the specialized versions of `add`, but I doubt it'd help much.

Comment: I guess the question can be summarized as: **"Is there a modern C++ approach that is equivalent to polymorphic function-like macros?"**

Comment: @K.G. "Is there a modern C++ approach that is equivalent to polymorphic function-like macros?" Yes, usage of templates and type traits (though true polymorphism can be tricky to pull off with template arguments depending on what you're trying to do). While performance will certainly deteriorate due to wrapper class usage/function call overhead in non-optimized code, most modern compilers will automatically inline such short fragments when using optimized builds anyway so you should be fine there.